# How to generate a parser generator using Xtext?

Tags: xtext, parser-generator

I am planning to implement a meta language on top of Xtext. In other words, I am using the Xtext grammar to define my own meta language. This meta language can then be used to define a language (using the syntax that I defined). Using the defined language, a model can be created by the user.

Hence, I would like to use Xtext/Xtend as a generator for parser generators. This would enable me to add as many meta levels as I like. My understanding is, that Xtext itself is defined using Xtext, so this should be possible?

The problem is that I don't know how to approach this, as I am not an expert in Xtext or parser generator frameworks in general. Any solutions/approaches/hints are welcomed.

**Update (more details and motivation)**

Xtext can be used to generate anything, so I could write a generator based on Xtext that generates a parser. This could be done by specifying my meta language's grammar, using Xtext to generate a parser for that grammar, so I would have access to an AST that represents a model written in my meta language.  However, from here on, I would be left alone to do whatever I want with the AST, e.g. generate a parser (because the AST represents the grammar of a user-defined language). But as Xtext has the specific ability to generate parsers, I was thinking of reusing this feature instead of implementing my own parser generator based on the AST of a grammar.

My motivation is the wish to define my own DSL grammar language (as a replacement for Xtext), while still being able to use the infrastructure provided by the Xtext project.

Comment: am not sure if i can follow you. in Xtext you can write generators. you can do whatever you want there. if the generated code itself is a parser. then you have a parser generator. the question for me: what would be the benefit on this approch?

Comment: Please check my update, I hope I could describe more clearly what my problem and motivation are. If anything specific is still unclear, I will add to this.

Comment: How would your grammar differ from Xtext grammar Lang

Comment: I would like to add some convenience features, that could e.g. simplify symbol table generation (this is one of the features which I need in all of my DSLs, so it would be neat to include this functionality at this level)

Comment: Am not sure but won’t extending Xtext or simply writing some fragments for the workflow do the same

Comment: Yes, probably, but this is more limited. Using my (theoretical) approach, you would also be able to completely change the syntax of the grammar language, without loosing the benefits of Xtext. It would be possible to add as many meta levels as you want, with each one using the additional functionality provided by the lower level. It's similar to a layered software architecture, where you could have two layers and include everything that is needed in the first layer and bloat that up, or add multiple layers.

Comment: It seems to me the hard part will be to implement the semantics of your metalanguage, not the syntax.

Comment: Well, I already habe an idea in how to handle the semantics, my main problem is handling the syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

I came to the following solution:
A grammar that was written using my grammar language will be parsed by Xtext. Next, the resulting AST is transformed to the Xtext grammar language AST, which can be used as input for the existing parser generator.

In general, given some grammar language l1, a model written in this language will be parsed and the resulting AST will be transformed to the AST of the grammar language l2 that was used to specify l1. This step is repeated until we have an AST representing a model of the Xtext grammar language, which will be used to generate the new parser.

Naturally, any information added with the definition of a new grammar language will be lost in each transformation step. Therefore, the infrastructure that is developed around a grammar language has the responsibility to create some kind of functionality that makes this information available to a higher language developed using the grammar language.

Answer (score 0):

For a different approach, see:

WWW.XTRAN-LLC.com/xtran.html#parse-gen

In a nutshell, I got tired of creating parsers for XTRAN, our Expert System whose rules language manipulates computer languages, data, and text, so I created a parsing engine that directly executes EBNF at parse time (as opposed to creating parsing code, e.g. Lexx/YACC and ANTLR).  Since XTRAN must also render code content represented in its Internal Representation / AST (after it's manipulated) as source code text, I created a corresponding rendering engine that executes (a much simpler form of) EBNF at render time.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting approach, but I don't really understand how this would provide me benefits for solving my problem. Maybe you could elaborate on that.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you think outside the box, as I did.  Also take a look at SNOBOL, a text parsing language from the 1970s ff., which made it easy to construct parsers for a wide variety of languages.  I did some really cool stuff in SNOBOL back then.

Comment: I don't mind thinking out of the box, I just didn't know how the XTRAN approach would be helpful for me. I will also take a look at SNOBOL. However, my original intention was to find out if the concept that I have in my head would be implementable using Xtext. Whether the concept is the most feasible one is a different question.